# Split up single object into multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a single JSON object that I would like to split up into multiple objects. I've tried converting the single JSON object into an array. I couldn't figure out a pattern to break up the single object if there's an absent key, i.e. meal1, meal2, etc. I'm not even sure if this is the best approach. I appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction!

Before

```
{
  "fullName1" : "John Doe",
  "attendance1" : 1,
  "meal1" : "salmon",
  "fullName2" : "Jane Doe",
  "attendance2" : 0
}
```

Desired result

```
{
  "fullName" : "John Doe",
  "attendance" : 1,
  "meal" : "salmon"
},
{
  "fullName" : "Jane Doe"
  "attendance" : 0
}
```

As far as my attempt, this is how far I've gotten:

```
const entries = [...elements];
// check for valid elements
const isValidElement = element => {
  return element.name && element.value;
};
const isValidValue = element => {
  return (!['radio'].includes(element.type) || element.checked);
};
const formToJSON = elements =>
  [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
    if (isValidElement(element) && isValidValue(element)) {
      data[element.name] = element.value;
    }
    return data;
  }, {});
//
const singleArray = formToJSON(entries);
```

Comment: Are the keys known? Where's your attempt at solving this on your own? We don't just hand out solutions. (also, there no such thing as a "JSON object"; what you're showing is a JavaScript Object literal)

Comment: This isn't an array. Also, your criteria for splitting up the object seems unclear. Is it the suffixes in the property names?

Comment: This is an object, not an array, so you can't use any of the array methods you mentioned. In fact, since it's just a plain object with no substructure, I think you'll basically have to do this manually.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the feedback. I've tried converting the JSON into an array by using `Array.from()` and trying to manipulate from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` and `reduce` like below to achieve this

Loop through every record in the object, and store last digits from the key in temp Object.

```js
let obj = {
  "fullName1" : "John Doe",
  "attendance1" : 1,
  "meal1" : "salmon",
  "fullName2" : "Jane Doe",
  "attendance2" : 0
}

let res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
    let [name, number] = k.match(/\D+|\d+$/g)
    o[number] = { ...(o[number] || {}), [name]: v }
    return o
  }, {})
  
console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: Thank you Nitish! I appreciate it! May I ask what `o` means? After reviewing the possible parameters (Accumulator (acc), Current Value (cur), Current Index (idx), Source Array (src)), just trying to better understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Welcome @drukelly. `o` is temp object which `reduce` will save for every iteration. As you can see it is always the first argument of  `reduce` You can call it whatever you want. This value is initialised by us as the last argument  in `reduce`(which in this case is empty object).

Comment: I like to call it `o` when I need `reduce` to work on objects and `a` when I want it to work on arrays. You can call it anything. But it is what is returned at the end.

Comment: Oh!! This is an `accumulator` only

Comment: Thanks again Nitish! Your subsequent reply after my comment explains it! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how many objects there would be, it would best to split them into an array of objects. First iterate over the keys then check its index. This assumes keys ALWAYS ends with a number and the number at the end is always the index.

```js
var obj = {
  "fullName1" : "John Doe",
  "attendance1" : 1,
  "meal1" : "salmon",
  "fullName2" : "Jane Doe",
  "attendance2" : 0
};
var objs = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  var match = key.match(/(.*)(\d.*)$/);
  var newKey = match[1];
  var index = parseInt(match[2]) - 1;
  objs[index] = objs[index] || {};
  objs[index][newKey] = obj[key];
})
console.log(objs);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've made my day! I'd totally upvote (and maybe I will when I have enough rep points)

Answer (score 0):

here how to split in three equal chunks

```
const splitIntoThreeChunks = (obj) => {
    let obj1 = {}
    let obj2 = {}
    let obj3 = {}

    const keys = Object.keys(obj)
    const keysLength = keys.length
    let k = 0

    for (let i = 0; i <= keysLength; i++) {
        const key = keys[i]
        if (k === 0) {
            obj1 = { ...obj1, [key]: obj[key] }
            k++
        } else if (k === 1) {
            obj2 = { ...obj2, [key]: obj[key] }
            k++
        } else if (k === 2) {
            obj3 = { ...obj3, [key]: obj[key] }
            k = 0
        }
    }

    return {
        obj1,
        obj2,
        obj3
    }
}
```